# My GS4 won't boot to CWM?

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung, odin

So, I've tried flashing CMW a few times with different files, etc. ODIN says that the flashing was a success, and according to ROM Manager, it's installed. However, when I hold volume up and power and home to boot to CWM, it just boots to the Samsung recovery. ROM Manager also says I have TWRP installed. My phone is not rooted. Could that be why? If no, why isn''t it working